# Crisp text on top of 3d-transformed element in Safari

Tags: safari, 3d, css, transformation

I need to float some text on top of some elements that have been transformed using `-webkit-transform:translate3d()`. The problem I've found is that the only way I've been able to stack an element on top of anything that has been 3d-transformed, is to use `translate3d()` as well and place it above on the z-axis. That's okay for images and shapes, but it's terrible for text, which comes out unacceptably blurry.

Is there some way to either float non-3d-transformed text on top of a 3d-transformed element or to preserve the crispness of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a 3d transform just to get text to float, just set z-indexes on both the background and the text. That said, text rendering can be very unpredictable when combined with 3D animation (and mobile safari tends to be far better at rendering than desktop safari, so if you're previewing something for mobile - really do look at it on your actual iphone.)

That said, there are a few things you can try to get text not to look all IE6 in desktop safari.

1) Set the font-weight to light but then add a one pixel -webkit-text-stroke in a lighter tone than your text 
2) Add a text-shadow in a lighter tone with a zero offsets and a 1 or 2 pixel blur
3) Make the font size be very large and scale it using 3D transforms to the size you need. 
4) Use font-smoothing

Comment: This did turn out to be the right answer. I'm using [ZFlow](http://code.google.com/p/css-vfx/wiki/AboutZflow) for a coverflow-style animation and I'm good enough at CSS to control the `z-index` stacking, but that didn't seem to be enough. What I think ended up working was using `z-index` and `translate3d()` on all stackable layers. In the end, the floating text didn't appear to scale at all, but still had a positive-Z orientation. I'll try to post my code later once I clean it up and make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a zero or negative value to *z* in translate3d(x, y, z) then you can position things above the transformed elements, i.e:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0)
```

Here is a test case that works on Safari:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqFNY/

Comment: Thanks for the answer... and sorry for not responding right away. Unfortunately, in this case, I will always have things in the positive Z. In other circumstances, I think applying a `translateZ()` to the entire enclosing `<div>` and forcing it to stay in negative Z would probably work, but it's not possible in the code I'm using.